# Submitting form jQuery checkboxlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, event-handling

In my requestForm submit function I have this logic that checks three checkboxes and then displays the label with an error message. Is there better logic? I would be happy for any kind of feedback since this is quite critical a part of my application.

```
$("#requestForm").submit(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();


        var checked_sourcecheckboxes = $("#sources input[type=checkbox]:checked");
        if (checked_sourcecheckboxes.length == 0) {
            $("#lblSourcesError").show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#lblSourcesError").hide();
        }
        var checked_academicformatcheckboxes = $("#academicFormatsRow input[type=checkbox]:checked");
        if (checked_academicformatcheckboxes.length == 0) {
            $("#lblacademicFormatError").show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#lblacademicFormatError").hide();
        }
        var checked_academicmediaformatcheckboxes = $("#academicMediaFormatRow input[type=checkbox]:checked");
        if (checked_academicmediaformatcheckboxes.length == 0) {
            $("#lblacademicmediaFormatError").show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#lblacademicmediaFormatError").hide();
        }
})
```

Comment: what about the `return false;` logic? that will stop the loop

Comment: You also should post the HTML. Because I would suggest some change... It seems you only use `id` and you could have a way simpler logic if you'd use classes on the checkboxes and error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Main Question

> Is there better logic?

#### Repeated code

The first thing that I see with this code, which perhaps you see also, is that it is quite repetitive - select a list of checkboxes to see if any are checked - if none are checked then show an error message and return, otherwise hide any affiliated error message. This violates the [**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself principle](https://deviq.com/principles/dont-repeat-yourself). It can be remedied by abstracting the common logic - e.g. putting the  the selectors into a mapping:

```
var SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING = {
    "#sources input[type=checkbox]:checked": "#lblSourcesError", 
    "#academicFormatsRow input[type=checkbox]:checked": "lblacademicFormatError",
    //...more entries
};
```

Then use a loop to iterate over the mapping, checking each selector - e.g. using [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#browser_compatibility):

```
return Object.keys(SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING).every(function(selector) {
    var errorSelector = SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING[selector];

    var showError = !$(selector).length;
    $(errorSelector).toggle(showError, errorSelector);
    return !showError;
});
```

Those last three lines of the inner function could be placed into a separate function if desired, which would allow for better modularization/atomization and testing.

#### demo

```js
var SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING = {
  "#sources input[type=checkbox]:checked": "#lblSourcesError",
  "#academicFormatsRow input[type=checkbox]:checked": "#lblacademicFormatError",
  "#academicMediaFormatRow input[type=checkbox]:checked": "#lblacademicmediaFormatError",
  //...more entries
};
$("#requestForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var allValid = Object.keys(SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING).every(function(selector) {
    var errorSelector = SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING[selector];

    var showError = !$(selector).length;
    $(errorSelector).toggle(showError, errorSelector);
    return !showError;
  });
  console.log('result', allValid);
  return allValid;
})
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="requestForm">
  <div id="sources">
    <h3> Source </h3>
    <label>Audi 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="Audi" />
    </label>
    <label>BMW 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="BMW" />
    </label>
    <div class="error" id="lblSourcesError" style="display: none">Please select a source</div>
  </div>
  <div id="academicFormatsRow">
    <h3> Formats </h3>
    <label>College 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="college" />
    </label>
    <label>University
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="university" />
    </label>
    <div class="error" id="lblacademicFormatError" style="display: none">Please select a format</div>

  </div>
  <div id="academicMediaFormatRow">
    <h3> Media Formats </h3>
    <label>DVD 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="DVD" />
    </label>
    <label>Blue-ray
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="blueray" />
    </label>
    <div class="error" id="lblacademicmediaFormatError" style="display: none">Please select a media format</div>

  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Modern browsers support client-side validation using the `required` attribute on input elements<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)</sup> and it is supported for checkbox inputs<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#validation)</sup> but apparently setting a custom message for checkboxes still involves writing some JavaScript<sup>[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38853115/1575353)</sup>.

#### HTML layout

As one comment suggested, the dependence on the *id* attribute could be decreased - For example, if the location of the error message element was consistent within each section -e.g. a sibling of the list of checkbox inputs. Another solution might be to have each section of checkboxes and error message contained by a parent element with a consistent class name- then the JavaScript could loop over those container elements looking to see if the checkbox elements have any checked- if not, then display the error message.

## Other review points

### ES6

With modern JavaScript, consider using newer EcmaScript-2015 (AKA ES6) features, like [`for...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), the keywords `let` and `const` instead of `var`, etc.

### jQuery

Also consider whether you really need jQuery because [it may be the case it can be replaced with “vanilla JS” features](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). For example, to select elements with a CSS selector use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and to add an event listener for the form submission, use [the `addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) after selecting that form element - e.g. with `document.getElementById('requestForm')`, `document.forms[0]` unless it isn't the first form, etc..

### Loose comparisons

In the original code the length property of the jQuery objects was compared with 0 using loose equality - i.e. `==`. A good habit and recommendation of many style guides is to use strict equality operators (i.e. `===`, `!==`) whenever possible. The problem with loose comparisons is that it has [so many weird rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494) one would need to memorize in order to be confident in its proper usage.

The suggested code above and below simplified this by using `!$(checkboxSelector).length;`

#### demo

```js
const SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING = {
  "#sources input[type=checkbox]:checked": "#lblSourcesError",
  "#academicFormatsRow input[type=checkbox]:checked": "#lblacademicFormatError",
  "#academicMediaFormatRow input[type=checkbox]:checked": "#lblacademicmediaFormatError",
  //...more entries
};
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  for (const [selector, errorSelector] of Object.entries(SELECTOR_ERROR_MAPPING)) {
    const showError = !document.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
    document.querySelector(errorSelector).classList.toggle('hidden', !showError);
    if (showError) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="requestForm">
  <div id="sources">
    <h3> Source </h3>
    <label>Audi 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="Audi" />
    </label>
    <label>BMW 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="BMW" />
    </label>
    <div class="error hidden" id="lblSourcesError">Please select a source</div>
  </div>
  <div id="academicFormatsRow">
    <h3> Formats </h3>
    <label>College 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="college" />
    </label>
    <label>University
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="university" />
    </label>
    <div class="error hidden" id="lblacademicFormatError">Please select a format</div>

  </div>
  <div id="academicMediaFormatRow">
    <h3> Media Formats </h3>
    <label>DVD 
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="DVD" />
    </label>
    <label>Blue-ray
      <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="blueray" />
    </label>
    <div class="error hidden" id="lblacademicmediaFormatError">Please select a media format</div>

  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```